# changing one attr name but different values for group of elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am in process of learning jQuery. I was practicing some examples from the book reading about attr(), removeAttr(), each() functions. I decided to try different tasks and one of them was to change href attribute for  a list of links( like 4 or 5 in the list), but I needed the value to be different for each link.

Here are my links:

```
<h1>My Favorite Shopping List!</h1>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google!</a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com"  target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
<a href="https://www.ebay.com" target="_blank">Ebay!</a>
<a href="https://www.amazon.com" target="_blank">Amazon</a>
```

Then I can use each() and attr() functions to loop through the links and change the attribute href to value www.facebook.com for example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).attr( 'href', 'http://www.facebook.com');
   });
});
```

the final result is:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Google!</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"  target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Ebay!</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Amazon</a>
```

But what is the possible solution if I want different values for ech link like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Google!</a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com"  target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank">Ebay!</a>
<a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">Amazon</a>
```

Considering less coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.    [Difference between `.prop` & `.attr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var linksArray = ["https://www.facebook.com", "https://www.instagram.com"] //all links
 $('a').each(function(i,v) {
      $(this).prop( 'href', linksArray[i]);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an array with your different urls, then use index in `each` callback function to apply successively each url:

```
var urls = [
  'https://www.facebook.com',
  'https://www.instagram.com',
  'https://www.pinterest.com',
  'https://www.twitter.com'
];
$(document).ready(function(index) {
  $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('href', urls[index]);
   });
});
```